# How to determine number of rows meeting a certain condition?

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I created a data frame from another data set called CompleteData:

```
conditions=data.frame(CompleteData$CAD,CompleteData$CVD,CompleteData$AAA,CompleteData$PAD)
```

This data frame has 2000 rows of data, with potential values of either 0 or 1. (The values represent the presence or absence of a condition such as CAD or CVD). I am trying to determine how many rows have two or more conditions in this data frame.

My general plan was to use an *if statement* combined with a *for loop* to determine which rows have multiple conditions, and then add the number of rows together. Here is the function I created:

```
for (conditions in conditions)
{
  multiple.conditions=function(conditions)
  {
    if(sum(conditions)>1){return("multiple conditions")}else{
      return("0 or 1 condition")
    }
  }
}
```

I'm just stuck in trying to figure out how to apply the *for loop* so that it performs the *if statement* row by row. I tested the *if statement* portion, which comes out correct, but how to structure the *for loop* is confusing me. As this is an introductory-level class, we are limited in the types of functions we are able to use. In this case, we have learned the syntax of functions, creating nested functions, if statements, for loops, and while loops. Any ideas?

Comment: If you have a `data.frame` you can loop throug its rows using their position. In that case i suggest starting with `for (i in 1:nrow(condtions))`.

Answer (score 0):

What about just using `rowSums()`?

```
sum(rowSums(conditions)>1)

[1] 106
```

If you need to use a loop, you can do something like this:

```
mult_cond_rows = 0
for(i in 1:nrow(conditions)) {
  row = conditions[i,]
  if(sum(row)>1) mult_cond_rows = mult_cond_rows + 1
}
print(mult_cond_rows)

[1] 106
```

Input:

```
set.seed(123)
conditions = as.data.frame(setNames(
  lapply(1:4, \(i) sample(0:1,2000, replace=T, prob=c(.9,.1))),
  nm = c("CAD", "CVD", "AAA", "PA")
))
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! We haven't learned rowSums() yet, and I feel like the intention is to use some sort of loop.